# Visual Studio - Is there any way to make the "Output" and "Error List" windows not appear after a debugging session?

Tags: visual-studio

It just occurred to me, after years of closing these two windows after a debugging session, that there may be a way to turn them off.  I generally have the output window open while debugging and only check the error list periodically for warnings, and can always get to them if I want them anyway.  Hoping someone else may know of a way to stop the default behavior?

Comment: Which version? My understanding is that everything about windows (visibility, layout etc) is per-context - ie what is displayed while debugging and what is displayed while not-debugging are separate settings. So even if they weren't displayed to start with, you are always getting Output and Error List displayed when going from debugging to not-debugging?

Comment: At least in 2008 and 2010.  I can close the Output window while designing and debugging and it always comes back as soon as the debugging session ends.  Not 100% sure about the error list.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Visual Studio remembers the window layout for coding and debugging separately, so removing the output window *while* you are debugging will not affect the "coding" state - you need to close the output window before you debug or it will reappear when debugging finishes.

In Tools>Options, Projects and Solutions, there are options "Always show error list if build finishes with errors" and "Show output window when build starts" which cause the error/output windows to be shown automatically just before you start debugging. These could be the culprits for adding an error/output window that then reappears when you exit debugging mode.

[image]

I have the output window "dockable" and pinned open. When I want to see it I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, and to get rid of it I click into it and <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>escape</kbd>. The output window "magically" disappears whenever I dont want it, but if I pay close attention I can see that I'm hitting the hotkey automatically myself :-)

Comment: That checkbox in options was it - thanks, I thought it was probably there somewhere but had no luck finding it.

Comment: and whats for visual studio mac. . . . i could not found that option for mac.

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac is a completely separate product that Microsoft bought and rebranded, so it may not have the same settings as VS for the PC. I'm afraid I can't help you with the options it does have.